# algorithm complexity of pseudo code

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, complexity-theory

This is pseudo code for a function that turns decimal digits into binary representations.

The question is Show that Ldiv2[A] for an n-digit number is O(n).
and determine the running complexity of the algorithm

The input is a decimal representation of a number X, give by an array of digits A[n-1], …,

The following algorithm uses a “long division by two” procedure Ldiv2 that divides a decimal number by 2. The binary conversion algorithm below convert the array of decimal digits A[0..n-1] to the array of bits B[0, ..4n-1] as follows:

```
Initialize B[0, ..4n-1] array of bits,
For i = 0 to 4n-1 do:
    Begin
    B[i]= A[0] %2;   // % is the mod;
    A = Ldiv2[A];
    End;
Return B (possibly removing initial 0’s)
```

So for the above example X=169, n=2, B[0] = A[0]%2 = 9%2=1, then A=Ldiv2[A] = 84, B[1]=A[0]%2 = 4%2=0, etc.

for Ldiv2[A] i put that 4n-1 for n > 1 so that by definition should be O(n)
and for the running complexity of the algorithm i put it was O(n) too because it only has one for loop running from 0 to 4n -1 although bit unclear if there is proof for that.

Comment: `A` is not defined anywhere...

Comment: this was all that was provided as the pseudo code.

Comment: And what exactly is Ldiv2?

Comment: Then the provided question is missing an important input!

Comment: i edited the question to include more of the info given

Comment: well Ldiv2 has to be O(n), nm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run in a loop `4n-1` times and each time preform an action that takes in the beginning `O(n)` and `O(1)` at the end (when A turns to 1).

So we get:

```
(4n-1)*(n/log(n)) = O(n^2/log(n))
```

Comment: hmmm . . . ok im starting to understand it a bit now

Comment: Long division goes through every digit and preform an O(1) number of actions (including "carry over") hence it's total of O(n) for every long division (Ldiv2) of a number with n digits.

Comment: @alfasin A is an array of digits representing the number. If the number under consideration is 1024, then A[0] = 1, A[1] = 0, A[3] = 2, A[4] = 4. Hence, in the for loop, Ldiv2[A] gets an input which has a single digit. Hence, it should be O(1) according to you. Why is it O(n) in the beginning and O(1) at the end ?

Comment: @VivekS `Ldiv2[A]` is a bit confusing, it should have been written as `Ldiv2(A)` and then it's a bit more clear that Ldiv2 receives (in your example) an array of 4 digits as an input ;)

Comment: @alfasin "B[i] = A[0] % 2;" This means that inside the for loop we are just modifying one digit. Hence, I presume that Ldiv2(A) is actually Ldiv2(A[0]) as passing an entire array when you are still trying to figure out the binary representation of a single digit is pointless.

Comment: @VivekS you don't have to (wrongly) assume anything: the algorithm explicitly states that `A = Ldiv2[A];` which means that `A` (including all its digits) is the input for Ldiv2.

Comment: @alfasin i think you're right Ldiv2(A) would be better written

Comment: @alfasin the logn in your initial response comes because we are diving A by 2 each time hence decrease the number by 2 digits each time? not sure exactly how the logn plays into it, struggling to understand thanks for your help though

Comment: @user2321926 not decreasing it by two digits but I think that you got the idea. Say that the number that's stored in A is marked by `x`. And say that `2^n` is the "closest" number to `x` which is also greater than `x`. In that, `log(x) = n` (log with base 2). In other words, it'll take us `n` steps of dividing x with 2, and the divide the result in 2 again ... until we reach 1.